# Using variable in for loop in bash

Tags: variables, for-loop

Simple question:

Fetch numbers(i) from a list of number; then use each of the number to do sth.

```
for i in list_of_number;do cat file|head -$(($i+1))|tail -1;done
```

This seems right but actually doesn't work. What's the problem here?
thx

Answer (score 1):

Doing this will treat `list_of_number` as a string; I assume this is a file which contains a list of numbers that you want to loop over.

Try instead:

```
for i in `cat list_of_number`;do cat file|head -$(($i+1))|tail -1;done
```

Comment: no worries, I make these types of mistakes all the time.  Bash can be pretty unforgiving.